# Override test settings for a custom filesystem - How?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-settings

Somwhere in my models i have defined a filesystem, that specifies a custom place to save data for a users profile. It's really simple and looks like this:

```
social_user_fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.SOCIAL_USER_FILES,
                                   base_url=settings.SOCIAL_USER_URL)
```

which i then used in a model like this:

```
class SocialUserProfile(models.Model):

    def get_user_profileimg_path(self, filename):
        return '%s/profile_images/%s' % (self.user_id, filename)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_user_profileimg_path,
                              storage=social_user_fs,
                              blank=True)
```

This works very well and behaves like i expect it to. But now i ran into a problem with testing:

```
import os

from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.utils import override_settings

from social_user.forms import ProfileImageUploadForm #@UnresolvedImport
from social_user.models import SocialUserProfile #@UnresolvedImport

# point the filesystem to the subfolder data of app/test/
@override_settings(SOCIAL_USER_FILES = os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/testdata',
                   SOCIAL_USER_URL = 'profiles/')

class TestProfileImageUploadForm(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['social_user_profile_fixtures.json']

    def test_save(self):
        profile = SocialUserProfile.objects.get(pk=1)
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

The interactive debugging session gives me this:

```
ipdb> from django.conf import settings
ipdb> settings.SOCIAL_USER_FILES
'/Volumes/Data/Website/Backend/project/social_user/tests/testdata'
ipdb> settings.SOCIAL_USER_URL
'profiles/'
# ok, the settings have been changed, the filesystem should use the new values

ipdb> profile.image.url
'/user_files/profiles/1/profile_images/picture1-1.png' 
# 'profiles/1/profile_images/picture1-1.png'
# would be correct with the new settings
# the actual value still uses the original settings

ipdb> f = file(profile.image.file)
*** IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
u'/Volumes/Data/Website/Backend/user_files/profiles/1/profile_images/picture1-1.png'
# same here, overridden settings should result in
# '/Volumes/Data/Website/Backend/social_user/tests/testdata/1/profile_images/picture1-1.png'
```

So the settings have been overridden. It looks like my custom filesystem is just not reacting to the override of the settings. Why that? Is overriding possible, or is the filesystem initiated at a certain point and cannot be changed afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

I guess `social_user_fs` is global in its module, and you're importing stuff from that module outside the test. So it gets processed before calling test method (and the decorator).

Import `SocialUserProfile` inside `test_save`, i think it will be the best soultion.